# Fill N/A data based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file with 2 column `store_name` and `store_location` that some `store_location` is missing. And I want to fill missing data with data in same column based on value in another column.

**Below is my csv file:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hoatranobita/app_to_cloud_4/main/store_location.csv')
```

[image]

**Here is my expected Output:**

[image]

I tried to find solutions but still not find out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: providing 3 different approaches in case you want to:

1. ensure a unique value per group
2. fill the NaN with the first available value
3. fill the NaN with the previous/next non-NA row
4. Looks like you could need a unique value per group. Use `groupby.transform('first')` to get the first non-NA value:

```
df['store_location'] = df.groupby('store_name')['store_location'].transform('first')
```

output:

```
                             store_name                         store_location
0                       AJ's Liquor III           POINT (-93.648959 42.021456)
1                       AJ's Liquor III           POINT (-93.648959 42.021456)
2                Ambysure Inc / Clinton           POINT (-90.225022 41.833351)
3                Ambysure Inc / Clinton           POINT (-90.225022 41.833351)
4                 Bancroft Liquor Store               POINT (-94.218 43.29355)
5                 Bancroft Liquor Store               POINT (-94.218 43.29355)
6                                Bani's  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
7                  Bani's / Cedar Falls  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
8                  Bani's / Cedar Falls  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
9                      Barrys Mini Mart            POINT (-91.38553 43.050183)
10                 Baxter Family Market           POINT (-93.151465 41.826715)
11             Beecher Liquor / Dubuque  POINT (-90.696886 42.500775000000004)
12           Beer on Floyd / Sioux City  POINT (-96.372185 42.531448000000005)
13                  Beer Thirty Denison           POINT (-95.360162 42.012412)
14  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake           POINT (-95.198584 42.646794)
15  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake           POINT (-95.198584 42.646794)
16  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake           POINT (-95.198584 42.646794)
```

2. If there are different values and you want to preserve them, you can replace the NaN with the first non-NA value:

```
df['store_location'] = df['store_location'].fillna(df.groupby('store_name')['store_location'].transform('first'))
```

output:

```
                             store_name                         store_location
0                       AJ's Liquor III           POINT (-93.648959 42.021456)
1                       AJ's Liquor III           POINT (-93.648959 42.021456)
2                Ambysure Inc / Clinton           POINT (-90.225022 41.833351)
3                Ambysure Inc / Clinton           POINT (-90.225022 41.833351)
4                 Bancroft Liquor Store               POINT (-94.218 43.29355)
5                 Bancroft Liquor Store               POINT (-94.218 43.29355)
6                                Bani's  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
7                  Bani's / Cedar Falls  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
8                  Bani's / Cedar Falls  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
9                      Barrys Mini Mart            POINT (-91.38553 43.050183)
10                 Baxter Family Market           POINT (-93.151465 41.826715)
11             Beecher Liquor / Dubuque  POINT (-90.696886 42.500775000000004)
12           Beer on Floyd / Sioux City  POINT (-96.372185 42.531448000000005)
13                  Beer Thirty Denison           POINT (-95.360162 42.012412)
14  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake           POINT (-95.198584 42.646794)
15  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake   POINT (-95.19941700000001 42.647498)
16  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake           POINT (-95.198584 42.646794)
```

3. Alternatively, use the previous/next non-NA values per group with `ffill`+`bfill`:

```
df['store_location'] = df.groupby('store_name')['store_location'].transform(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill())
```

output:

```
                             store_name                         store_location
0                       AJ's Liquor III           POINT (-93.648959 42.021456)
1                       AJ's Liquor III           POINT (-93.648959 42.021456)
2                Ambysure Inc / Clinton           POINT (-90.225022 41.833351)
3                Ambysure Inc / Clinton           POINT (-90.225022 41.833351)
4                 Bancroft Liquor Store               POINT (-94.218 43.29355)
5                 Bancroft Liquor Store               POINT (-94.218 43.29355)
6                                Bani's  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
7                  Bani's / Cedar Falls  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
8                  Bani's / Cedar Falls  POINT (-92.455801 42.518018000000005)
9                      Barrys Mini Mart            POINT (-91.38553 43.050183)
10                 Baxter Family Market           POINT (-93.151465 41.826715)
11             Beecher Liquor / Dubuque  POINT (-90.696886 42.500775000000004)
12           Beer on Floyd / Sioux City  POINT (-96.372185 42.531448000000005)
13                  Beer Thirty Denison           POINT (-95.360162 42.012412)
14  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake           POINT (-95.198584 42.646794)
15  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake   POINT (-95.19941700000001 42.647498)
16  Beer Thirty Storm Lake / Storm Lake   POINT (-95.19941700000001 42.647498)
```